# Batch script to dynamically pass inputs to a .exe and run recursively

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, batch-file, exe

I am trying to run a batch script where it will be fetching Values from SQL Server table result set and pass that as an input in a loop to an .EXE in the batch script and run recursively.

**Example:**

```
SQL Query: 
select Name from sys.tables

SQL Query output: 
a
b
c

/*Now I have to pass the output of sql query values(a,b,c) I got above as an 
input to Test.exe parameter 3 times in a for or while loop specific to batch 
script one value at a time and executes the exe. 

Example of values passed to exe looks as below.


Test.exe a  -- 1st run in a loop
Test.exe b  -- 2nd run in a loop
Test.exe c  -- 3rd run in a loop

-- My code overview or assumption, I would need the below code snippet to be replaced 
and rewritten in a way it executes successfully using batch script.*/


declare @name int
set @name = count(Name) from sys.tables


DECLARE @Counter INT 

SET @Counter=1

WHILE ( @Counter <= @name)

BEGIN

    C:\Users> .\Test.exe /Input_From_Sql_result_as_argument @Name 

    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

I am new to batch scripting, if you can shed some ideas on implementing this in batch script it would be really helpful. Please let me know if I have to share any details..

Comment: I would, if you showed us the batch script. This is a .sql script, not batch.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yeah, final output and execution should go by running a batch file but the logic inside the batch file is dependend on result set derived from SQL table and which should inturn be passed as an input to an exe that will run in a loop based on the number of records came as output in sql table.

Comment: For the type of commands you've exampled, the batch equivelants you'll need are `for` `set` and `start` . In cmd.exe type each command followed by /? For the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of each line can be Set to an indexed variable, much like an array, with the aid of `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and a basic `For /F` loop

Depending on the content / structure of your file/s you may not need to bother with the Array approach - Just perform your action using the For /F loop Variable/s (%%G in this example).

Again, content dependent, you may want to modify the options in the for loop to retrieve specific tokens. (type `For /F` in cmd.exe for full syntax - or search and read through the numerous other questions on SO regarding processing file content)

Once you've established the array, you can use a `For /L` loop to iterate through each line and insert the commands to be enacted using the value of each line.

If, by running recursively you mean to run this on each file in folder and subfolders (the typical meaning of the term recursively where batch is concerned, Nest the `For /F` loop inside a `For /R` Loop, and exchange `%inputfile%` with `%%A` in the For /F loop like so:

CD (Change Directory) / PUSHD to the parent folder to be iterated over / or / Ensure the batch is run from the parent folder

`For /R %%A In (*.YOURextension) Do (For /F "delims=" %%G in (%%A) Do (commands))`

``

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set index=0
Set "inputFile=Your File Path.extension"
For /f "delims=" %%G in (%inputfile%) DO (
REM Perform your action on the content here using %%G
    ECHO(%%G
REM Optional - assign value of each line to indexed variable
    Set /a "index+=1"
    Set "Line[!index!]=%%G"
)

For /L %%I in (1,1,!index!) DO (
REM - Alternate - Perfom your action on the content here using !Line[%%I]!
    ECHO(!Line[%%I]!
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful :)